# Order levels of factors change after write csv and read csv in R

Tags: r

I have a hard time to figure out why order of levels of factor change after reading csv. When I am working on data, I always change order of levels by template of my report. Then I write it into csv file. Then I read that file again by read.csv with StringasFactor = False, or StringasFactor = True, it doesn't matter, the order of levels of factor change again, it's not look like the first time I set, so I have to set again to make tables like template. There is any package read csv without changing order of levels of factor. I appreciate.

Comment: Why do you write to csv rather than save as Rda?

Comment: I should save file in Rdata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordering isn't included in the CSV. The levels are being ordered alphabetically on import.

```
> xy <- data.frame(lvl = letters[1:5], num = rnorm(5))
> levels(xy$lvl)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
> factor(xy$lvl, levels = c(letters[5:1]))
[1] a b c d e
Levels: e d c b a
> xy$lvl <- factor(xy$lvl, levels = c(letters[5:1]))
> levels(xy$lvl)
[1] "e" "d" "c" "b" "a"
> write.table(xy, file = "test.txt", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = ";")
> read.table("test.txt", sep = ";", header = TRUE)
  lvl         num
1   a  0.20222642
2   b -0.09334365
3   c  0.45378860
4   d -0.32057560
5   e  0.74415174
> xy2 <- read.table("test.txt", sep = ";", header = TRUE)
> levels(xy2$lvl)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to have your data in csv format and keep your factor levels, you can use `csvy` package:

```
# library load
library(csvy)
library(dplyr)

# relevel factos
iris_releveled = iris %>% mutate(Species = relevel(Species, "virginica","setosa","versicolor"))
# write csv file
write.csv2(iris_releveled,"iris_releveled.csv")
# load exported dataset
iris_relevel_loaded = read.csv2("iris_releveled.csv",stringsAsFactors = T)
# now factor levels are lost
iris_relevel_loaded$Species %>% levels()

# write CSVy file from dataset with releveled factors
write_csvy(iris_releveled,  file = "iris_releveled.csvy")
# read csv file with original factor levels
iris_relevel_loaded = read_csvy("iris_releveled.csvy", stringsAsFactors = T)
# now factor levels are kept
iris_relevel_loaded$Species %>% levels()
```